# Auto generated accounts in Firebase after google sign in and published app in internal testing

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am developing an android app with firebase(auth, firestore, cloud, storage), still in prototype phase. Because I need to test Google Play Billing library for subscription functionalities, I published the app via internal testing in Google Play. I did that, however, few minutes after app was released (internal testing), I noticed some weird accounts being created in my firestore auth section, which were not generated by me or any other internal testers. This accounts are of course not on my testers list.[image]
I believe they were generated by google somehow, cause there's a login with google functionality implemented in my app.

Does anyone has an idea of where do they come from. Some time ago I did some research and I think someone mentioning something about autogenerated accounts, but am not finding anything related now. I need to get rid of them, cause I am "copying" each new account in firebase auth to a firestore collection - users, and am using some data further in my app. If anyone has an idea where do they come from or how should I not allow them (maybe some keys) or catch them automatically before they get "copied" to firestore collection.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely bots running your app to perform a pre-launch report in Firebase Test Lab.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842757?hl=en

> After you upload and publish a test Android App Bundle, we install it on a set of Android devices in our test lab. We then automatically launch and crawl your app for several minutes. The crawler performs basic actions such as typing, tapping, and swiping. You can also provide custom tests or test account credentials for the crawler to use.

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of them when the app will be released in production?

Comment: You can delete the accounts whenever you want.